# Still can't send SMS individually via Twilio extension

Tags: extension, sms

I keep getting

> One Message Not Sent
>
> A 'From' phone number is required. For more information, see https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603

... despite having followed all the setup instructions at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS#SettingupaSMSProviderforCiviSMS-twilio to the letter. Is something in the extension out of date? Something I need to change in the code to make it work with the current Civi iteration?

WP 4.7.2 / Civi 4.7.15

Answer (score 2):

The instructions on the Civi wiki weren't clear enough for my sleep-deprived brain. I had omitted the `From=` prefix from the API parameters in my SMS Provider Settings in Civi. Soon as I added `From=` to the front of our Trilio phone number, it worked like a charm.

Now to put some ice on this palm-shaped bruise on my forehead ...